# FSCK reports that filesystem still has errors

Tags: boot, fsck

I'm learning a little about `fsck` on the fly, but what I am finding so far doesn't seem to do very much when I apply it. What would be the next step from this prompt to repair the errors I am having when booting?

[image: fsck reports that filesystem still has errors - manual fsck required]

Answer (score 12):

### S.M.A.R.T. information of HDD and SSD

Check the S.M.A.R.T. information. It is easy using Disks alias `gnome-disks` according to this link,

[Reformating hard drive after malware damaged boot sector - scroll down to 'Maybe the disk hardware is damaged'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948036/reformating-hard-drive-after-malware-damaged-boot-sector/948560#948560)

Select S.M.A.R.T. via the button at (1) and check the overall assessment at (2).

[image]

### Run `fsck` on an `ext4` file system

When I use `fsck` on an `ext4` file system I boot from another drive and unmount the file system.

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the device letter and n is the partition number, in your case `/dev/sda1` according to the screenshot.

Sometimes it helps to run this command twice. Sometimes the file system is damaged beyond repair.

Sometimes there are bad sectors (hardware defects on the drive). Then you can  mark the bad sectors (and make the system avoid them) with the following command

```
sudo e2fsck -cfk /dev/sdxn
```

See the manual

```
man e2fsck
```

for more details, and the following link for more tips about repairing file systems,

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Comment: When bad blocking a drive, it's best to add new bad blocks to the **existing** bad block table with `sudo e2fsck -cfk /dev/sdxn`... BUT I'd check the SMART info first.

Comment: Bad blocks on a modern (21st century) disk are a sign of imminent demise. The idea of a bad block list has become pretty meaningless. Replace the disk instead. `e2fsck` failures are not nearly as bad, as they can be caused by transient problems. These do not require replacing the disk.

Comment: @heynnema Does this work on "read-only filesystem"? I have live Ubuntu up and running. Any commad I type will "check" error, I don't think it's repairing anything!

Comment: @PrabeshBhattarai It's a little unclear what your question/problem is. Please start a new question, and give me as much detail as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Update to an old question... I'll update my previous comment to include a read/write bad block test... as bad blocks only get remapped on a write... `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

Comment: @heynnema do I have to do this from live ubuntu? or can I do this in the normal functioning running mounted system? Is there a way? Since it says "/dev/sda6 is mounted."

Comment: @heynnema I have a loop of "read-only system" which i want to stop. The only way for me to have normal working ubuntu to press e in grub menu and change "ro" to "rw" in Linux boot image. i.e linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.2-x86_64 root=<uuid> rw  quiet

Comment: @PrabeshBhattarai it sounds like you need to do a `fsck`... not a bad block scan... but again, please start a new question so that I can fully answer it for you. Describe any details you have there.

Comment: @PrabeshBhattarai, You should check/repair a file system with `e2fsck` or `fsck` when it is unmounted, and the root file system of a running operating system is mounted. So yes, you should do it from a live Ubuntu system. -- But as heynnema wrote, please start a new question. You can link to it from here in order to help us find it. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that your HDD has badblocks or it is defunct. Do you see this message: `blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2048`?
It means that it is impossible to read this sector from physical device.

You need to boot from a LiveCD and check you drive with:

```
$ sudo smartctl -HA /dev/sda
```

and check the line
`SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`
and the line `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` should contain `0` in `RAW_VALUE` field.

If SMART self test is `PASSED` you can try to 'remap' badblocks with `badblocks` tool:

```
$ sudo badblocks -svo ~/msg.log /dev/sda
```

and run fsck after:

```
$ sudo fsck -a /dev/sda1
```

If SMART self test is `FAILED` you need to replace your HDD.

PS: All these steps you should do from LiveCD session. And you have to replace `/dev/sda` to your drive.

**Update [11.11.2017]:**
So I've checked one of my old HHDs with `badblocks` and I've got these messages in my `syslog`:

```
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.339691] ata2.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.339702] ata2.01: BMDMA stat 0x64
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.339711] ata2.01: failed command: READ DMA
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.339726] ata2.01: cmd c8/00:08:58:64:00/00:00:00:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.339726]          res 51/40:00:5b:64:00/00:00:00:00:00/f0 Emask 0x9 (media error)
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.339733] ata2.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.339738] ata2.01: error: { UNC }
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.364282] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380287] ata2.01: configured for UDMA/100
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380327] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380337] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] 
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380346] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380355] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 64 58 00 00 08 00
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380361] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 25691
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380369] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3211, async page read
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380410] ata2: EH complete
```

So, all messages about I/O errors came from the kernel. The most interesting thing I found is in this line:

```
Nov 10 13:46:55 router kernel: [  121.380346] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
```

As I understand it's a decoded message from disk's firmware. It seems that the firmware found an read error and tried to reallocate the sector and failed with it. Consequently, in our case `badblocks` was doing nothing except reading all the sectors and we could replace it with `dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/null`.

And now I'm totally agried with `sudodus`. The most appropriate solution is:

```
sudo e2fsck -cfk /dev/sdxn
```

Comment: Best not to run `badblocks` directly, but rather use `sudo e2fsck -ck /dev/sdxn`. Check `man badblocks` for more info.

Comment: In this case I want `badblocks` to remap badblocks to reserved area, not to feed it's output to `fsck`.

Comment: You're going to loose all of the pre-existing bad block information.

Comment: You didn't get the idea. Every HDD and SSD has `reserved` area. And if disk's `firmware` detects failed attempt to write to a sector it can remap this sector to one from reserved area. So when you'd try to access this sector you'd get data from remapped one. So nobody knows about this sector besides the firmware. Maybe this [article](https://superuser.com/questions/384095/how-to-force-a-remap-of-sectors-reported-in-s-m-a-r-t-c5-current-pending-sector#688764) will clear the topic.

Comment: +1 I see your point :-)  Do you *know* that badblocks will trigger the process to remap a bad sector to one from the reserved area?

Comment: @sudodus, writing to the bad sector will either correct it ( in the case where the data just got scrambled, possibly due to sudden power loss ), or cause it to be reallocated from the spare pool.  Unless you use the -w switch, `badblocks` only tries to read from the disk.  Even if you do that, I'm not sure if it will try to write to a block that it can't read first.

Comment: I had a disk with badblocks and I used `badblocks` tool to check this disk (without `-w` or `-n` options). The `Reallocated sectors count` was growing and I had related messages in `syslog` from the kernel. I cannot find any docs to prove my words, but I'll test one of such disks on Tuesday and report here.

Comment: The error message may also mean that the filesystem layout was constructed for a larger disk (which may happen when you start learning by playing as root)  and now the operating system tries to read what isn't there.   For this particular case it looks like sda1 may be placed incorrectly.