# Trying to install ubuntu via DVD

Tags: system-installation, tag

I'm trying to install ubuntu 17.10 via DVD onto my acer aspire v3-511.
I had an issue with Windows, where it would randomly wipe everything including the OS. 
I'm assumin the hardrive is on its way out?
When I'm trying to install UBUNTU it gets to the install point of "creating ext4 system for / in partition #1 of scsi" hangs at this point for ages and then fails.
Is there anything I can do, or shall we just assume my hardrive is broken?

Thanks in advance.
Ryan

Edit:
I've partitioned and formatted the drive to the correct settings both manually and through the install medium as well, and on multiple occasions it's failed

Comment: It is a good idea to check the Ubuntu iso file, but it is also very important to check the SMART status of the hard disk drive. (It is a waste of time to install Ubuntu into a failing drive.) See this link, [S.M.A.R.T. information of HDD and SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983#972983)

Comment: The hardrive had all OS removed off it when it crashed, and now it won't install any OS properly (I managed to install Windows on legacy bios, but kept crashing). I'm buying a new hardrive today so should be good to go when that's installed. Thanks for the response

Comment: Good luck with the new hard disk drive :-)

Comment: Well the hardrive was the issue, got the new hardrive and have dual boot with windows and ubuntu 17.10  just can't seem to be able install wine now 

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? In my 16.04 LTS I have the package version 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2. (in another version of Ubuntu, you might install another wine package.) -- What happens, when you try the following commands? `sudo apt update`; `sudo apt install wine`; If still a problem, I think it is better to ask a **new question** about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's Better to check your Ubuntu ISO copy, usually the problem lands to be from a corrupted ISO. Try burning another ISO image.

Comment: I've used the ubuntu iso to install ubuntu onto a portable hardrive since posting this, and it worked perfectly so I'm guessing the hardrive is gone. Thanks for the reply