# How to erase a surviving MBR and format a disk?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I'm trying to format a disk but whatever I try after a reboot the old partition is always there.

I tried to see the partition with fdisk and format again using mkfs.ext4

```
    mirto@mirto-C35:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

    Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
    Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
    Be careful before using the write command.


    Comando (m per richiamare la guida): p
    Disk /dev/sdb: 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x7f633251

    Dispositivo Avvio Start      Fine   Settori   Size Id Tipo
    /dev/sdb1          2048 500117503 500115456 238,5G 83 Linux

    Comando (m per richiamare la guida): q

    mirto@mirto-C35:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -F -F /dev/sdb1
    mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
    Creazione del file system con 62514432 4k blocchi e 15630336 inode
    Etichetta del file system=c0a5c02e-4c6c-42f4-88c9-70ba4a198346
    Backup del superblocco salvati nei blocchi: 
            32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
            4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

    Allocating group tables: fatto                            
    Scrittura delle tavole degli inode: fatto                            
    Creating journal (262144 blocks): fatto
    Scrittura delle informazioni dei super-blocchi e dell'accounting del file system:
```

The command enter a continous loop trying to write the super-bloks and in syslog I see:

```
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.053676] ata5.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.053694] ata5.00: cmd 35/00:40:70:22:dd/00:05:0e:00:00/e0 tag 28 dma 688128 out
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.053694]          res 51/04:40:70:22:dd/00:05:0e:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.053703] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.053709] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.139798] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.139816] ata5: EH complete
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.153651] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.153660] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.153670] ata5.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.153685] ata5.00: cmd 35/00:40:70:22:dd/00:05:0e:00:00/e0 tag 30 dma 688128 out
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.153685]          res 51/04:40:70:22:dd/00:05:0e:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.153693] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.153698] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.238259] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.238280] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.238282] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.238284] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.238286] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0e dd 22 70 00 05 40 00
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.238287] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 249373296
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.238387] ata5: EH complete
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.273636] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.273641] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.273645] ata5.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.273652] ata5.00: cmd 35/00:40:b0:27:dd/00:05:0e:00:00/e0 tag 2 dma 688128 out
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.273652]          res 51/04:40:b0:27:dd/00:05:0e:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.273655] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.273657] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.328424] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.328436] ata5: EH complete
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.353667] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.353672] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.353675] ata5.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.353682] ata5.00: cmd 35/00:40:b0:27:dd/00:05:0e:00:00/e0 tag 4 dma 688128 out
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.353682]          res 51/04:40:b0:27:dd/00:05:0e:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.353685] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.353687] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.457184] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
    May  6 10:19:10 mirto-C35 kernel: [ 3778.457198] ata5: EH complete
```

Seems that the disk is protected and I cannot write on it.

How can I clear this disk?

**UPDATE**

The disk is a Plextor SSD

```
PLEXTOR PX-256M6G-2280
```

The output of hdparm is

```
    mirto@mirto-C35:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb
    [sudo] password di mirto: 

    /dev/sdb:

    ATA device, with non-removable media
            Model Number:       PLEXTOR PX-256M6G-2280                  
            Serial Number:      P02439111419        
            Firmware Revision:  1.00    
            Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
    Standards:
            Used: ATA/ATAPI-7 T13 1532D revision 4a 
            Supported: 8 7 6 5 & some of 8
    Configuration:
            Logical         max     current
            cylinders       16383   16383
            heads           16      16
            sectors/track   63      63
            --
            CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
            LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
            LBA48  user addressable sectors:   500118192
            Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
            Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
            Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
            device size with M = 1024*1024:      244198 MBytes
            device size with M = 1000*1000:      256060 MBytes (256 GB)
            cache/buffer size  = unknown
            Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
    Capabilities:
            LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
            Queue depth: 32
            Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
            R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
            DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
                Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
            PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
                Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
    Commands/features:                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            Enabled Supported:                                                                                                                                                                                         
            *    SMART feature set                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    Security Mode feature set                                                                                                                                                                          
            *    Power Management feature set                                                                                                                                                                       
            *    Write cache                                                                                                                                                                                        
            *    Look-ahead
            *    Host Protected Area feature set
            *    WRITE_BUFFER command
            *    READ_BUFFER command
            *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                    SET_MAX security extension
            *    48-bit Address feature set
            *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
            *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
            *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
            *    SMART error logging
            *    SMART self-test
            *    General Purpose Logging feature set
            *    64-bit World wide name
            *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
            *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
            *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
            *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
            *    Host-initiated interface power management
            *    Phy event counters
            *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                    Device-initiated interface power management
            *    Software settings preservation
                    Device Sleep (DEVSLP)
            *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
            *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
            *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
            *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
            *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
    Security: 
                    supported
            not     enabled
            not     locked
                    frozen
            not     expired: security count
                    supported: enhanced erase
            6min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 6min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
    Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50023031002d3f41
            NAA             : 5
            IEEE OUI        : 002303
            Unique ID       : 1002d3f41
    Device Sleep:
            DEVSLP Exit Timeout (DETO): 100 ms (drive)
            Minimum DEVSLP Assertion Time (MDAT): 10 ms (drive)
    Checksum: correct
    mirto@mirto-C35:~$
```

Comment: What kind of media is this? Flash? At least some USB devices (e.g. SanDisk) go read-only as too many bad blocks has been detected. The only thing you can do at that time is backup and replace. Note that Sandisk has (had?) nice warranties.

Comment: plz send more disk info sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb

Answer (score 0):

I think the following links will help you analyze the problem, and let us hope, solve it.

- [S.M.A.R.T. information of HDD and SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983#972983)

  - using **Disks** alias `gnome-disks`
- [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

  - testing in different ways
  - using **`mkusb`** to wipe/restore the drive

    - if successful **`gparted`** and other tools to create partitions and file systems should work
    - otherwise I think the drive is damaged and difficult tho repair with the tools available to normal users like you and me

Comment: Still trying your suggestions

Comment: @MirtoBusico, Good luck :-) and please come back and report the result, whatever it is.

Comment: still failing. Tried sudo mkusb and the "Restore to a standard storage device": it say the operation is completed; but the partition and its content is still there. Tried "sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1" that asks for confirmation for a zillion of corrections; but at the end the partition is still there. Seens the drive is readonly.

Comment: @MirtoBusico, Yes, I think so too: The drive is read-only, 'gridlocked', in other words damaged in a way that is difficult [read: impossible] to repair with the tools available to normal users like you and me :-(