# Resizing partition with 18.04 does not succeed with GParted

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, gparted

I have Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) installed on 1 partition (ext 4) using whole disk. I want to downsize it with GParted running from live USB, but after resizing, 18.04 does not boot, showing lots of errors.

I was able to try several times, because I have an ISO image of the system and I recreate it after with Clonezilla.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you use grub?   Grub stage 1 sits in the MBR (master boot record; or first 512 byte sector of HDD), which is really little more than a pointer to where the later stages of grub are (these reside in /boot/).  It could be your 'resize' caused stages 1.5 & 2 of grub to move position on the disk, and thus you need to re-write the MBR to point to the new location?  Do you use grub? & MBR? or use eufi?

Comment: Do not move the head end of the partition. It should work to move the tail end of the partition to shrink the partition. Maybe it helps to check/repair the file system: run `sudo e2fsck -cf /dev/sdx1` where x is the drive letter, for example a or b. See [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) for more details. (Try with `gparted` after you have checked/repaired the file system. You can also check the [S.M.A.R.T. information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983#972983).

Comment: when I run : e2fsck -cf /dev/sda1   i get :

kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

how to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](/q/126153/175814) followed by [How can I repair grub?](/q/88384/175814)