# Unable to delete files and folders

Tags: 16.04, rm

I am trying to delete some regular files in my machine (external hard-disk). It will throw the below errors,

```
rm: cannot remove 'Personal/Mobile': Input/output error 
rm: cannot remove 'Personal/mygarrage': Input/output error 
rm: cannot remove 'Personal/Photos': Input/output error 
rm: cannot remove 'Personal/typewriting': Input/output error
```

The actual file permissions looks,

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ ls -ltr
ls: cannot access 'Mobile': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'mygarrage': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'Photos': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'typewriting': Input/output error
total 4
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? typewriting
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? Photos
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? mygarrage
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? Mobile
```

What is the problem of this? Is there any way to delete this files?

File system info:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   18M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/sdb       iso9660   1.4G  1.4G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  1.4G  1.4G     0 100% /rofs
/cow           overlay   7.8G  2.1G  5.8G  26% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G  344K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G  932K  7.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   84K  1.6G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sda7      ext4      379G  229G  131G  64% /media/ubuntu/1c328b87-efa9-48d7-b98a-a28809d7a7c6
/dev/sdd1      fuseblk   932G  440G  492G  48% /media/ubuntu/SeagateBackupPlusDrive
```

Comment: Try `find Personal/Mobile -delete`. See if that error repeats

Comment: Are you able to list the files using `sudo ls -l`?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Getting find: ‘Mobile’: Input/output error

Comment: @αғsнιη No. Not running live.

Comment: I can suspect both a software and a hardware failure. For example, there might be something wrong with the file system. 1. What file system is it? 2. What kind of drive is it (brand name and model, and how is it connected to the computer)?

Comment: @Ravexina Still getting the same error

Comment: Then  it might be hardware failure...

Comment: @sudodus I am trying to delete  files in external hard disk (seagate -1TB). (*I missed for mentioning in post, now updated!)

Comment: output of dmesg? Also what is the fs type?

Comment: You help us help you, if you answer all questions (that are possible to answer).

Comment: @j-money dmesg print so many logs. I have updated about the file system infos.

Comment: @Rinzwind Updated file info in post.

Comment: So it is a live (I guess live-only) system and an installed system (`/dev/sda7`). It should mean that there is a root file system with an *`ext`* file system. This means that, when booted into the live system, unmount the partition `/dev/sda7` and then try to repair its file system like so, `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda7`; See more details at [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Answer (score 2):

### Try to repair the file system

Depending on file system, there are different ways that you can try to repair it according to this link:

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986).

### S.M.A.R.T. information

You should also check the 'hardware health', the S.M.A.R.T. information according to the following link:

[S.M.A.R.T. information of HDD and SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983#972983)

Answer (score 0):

[Read about mount/umount](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-and-unmount-file-systems-in-linux/)

In my case directory had be unmount, to be deleted itself or its subdirectories/files

`sudo umount -f /media/sami/OS\ WIN7`

Then simply `sudo rm -rf sami/OS\ WIN7` worked for me