# Health check of external hard drives

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ntfs, smart

What is best way to analyse the health of a large external 2TB/3TB/4TB USB hard drive with NTFS partitions in Ubuntu quickly?

I want to get some diagnostic data on overall health of the hard drive without doing an in depth scan.

So far I know gnome-disk-utility and gsmartcontrol.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd use the `smartctl` or `gnome-disks` tools you have already mentioned; they read the health of the drive from the circuitry of the drive itself, and not file-system, thus do not care if the drive contains ntfs, ext, btrfs, xfs or any other file system.  They also provide quick (historical stats only) so you can use without any scans.

Comment: I think it is easiest to use Disks alias `gnome-disks` (part of the package `gnome-disk-utility`) which is normally installed by default with Ubuntu. See this link for more details, [S.M.A.R.T. information of HDD and SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983#972983)

Comment: `smartctl` can be very useful when checking drives. Best to check what smartmon tools supports when it comes to external USB drives: https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices  I did have to blacklist `uas` for my external USB drive so that even `gnome-disks` could run the smart checks on it.

Answer (score 3):

You've already mentioned the use of the SMART features found in the `Disks` app, `Tests & Data`, and `gsmartcontrol`. A+

Another quick thing that you can do is to monitor `/var/log/syslog*` in terminal, like so...

```
grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*
```

- change sda to your desired drive to search for
- note the trailing * after syslog