# The package usb-creator-gtk needs to be reinstalled (NOT WORKING)

Tags: 16.04, python, 64-bit

> **Which version (for example 18.04.1 LTS) and which flavour (standard Ubuntu or a community flavour for example Lubuntu or Xubuntu) are your running?**
>
> **Processor** : Intel® Core™ i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4
>
> **Base System** : Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS 64-bit
>
> ---
>
> **Is the computer connected to the internet?**
>
> Yes
>
> ---
>
> **If installed, were there any errors during the installation?**
>
> No
>
> ---
>
> **Did it work before (and stopped working for some reason), or has it never worked (to install programs)?**
>
> Yes, it was working before, it happend right after i was trying to install python 3.6, i may have removed some python librarly/folder
>   that is required by "usb-creator-gtk" package.
>
> ---

Whenever I try to install anything this error comes up, Example i'm trying to install anydesk or any other software

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.6-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python2.7' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.5-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python2.7-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python2.7-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 194325 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack anydesk_5.1.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop anydesk.service: Unit anydesk.service not loaded.
Unpacking anydesk (5.1.1) over (5.1.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of anydesk:
 anydesk depends on libgtkglext1; however:
  Package libgtkglext1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package anydesk (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 anydesk
```

I tried this command,

```
 sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

Giving me this output,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package usb-creator-gtk needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Following command updated

```
apt-cache policy usb-creator-gtk
```

**Output**

```
usb-creator-gtk:
  Installed: 0.3.2ubuntu16.04.1
  Candidate: 0.3.2ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.3.2ubuntu16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Which version (for example 18.04.1 LTS) and which flavour (standard Ubuntu or a community flavour for example Lubuntu or Xubuntu) are your running? Is it installed (or live booted from a USB drive)? Is the computer connected to the internet? If installed, were there any errors during the installation? Did it work before (and stopped working for some reason), or has it never worked (to install programs)? **Please edit your original question** to answer my questions.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy usb-creator-gtk` to the question.

Comment: Sure i will update everything , give me time till monday, actually this issue is my facing in office laptop, first thing morning monday,i will update this question

Comment: @N0rbert Please check i've updated the command that you've mentioned

Comment: @sudodus Please check I've updated my question in details, please let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

In my installed 18.04.1 LTS I have Python 2.7, as indicated by the following command.

```
$ LANG=C apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.15~rc1-1
  Candidate: 2.7.15~rc1-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.15~rc1-1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I think you are right, when you suspect that the problem is the attempt to install Python 3.6.

I suggest that you try to remove it

```
sudo apt remove name-of-your-python-3.6-package
```

and after that try to reinstall the python2.7 package

```
sudo apt install python2.7
```

I am not sure that `apt` will be able to remove your Python 3.6 package and (re)install Python 2.7, and I don't know what to do if not, maybe use

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg -r package-name  # to remove
sudo dpkg -i package-name  # to install
```

If still problems, we need help from someone who knows more about repairing vital parts of Ubuntu, maybe [@oldfred](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863385&p=11359266#post11359266).

Comment: Sir after running the first command this is the output LANG=C apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     2.7.12-1~16.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: And after trying this `sudo apt remove name-of-your-python-3.6-package` this says this `E: The package usb-creator-gtk needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
`

Comment: @Vipertecpro, At this stage, will it be possible to install `python2.7` with `apt` or maybe with a `dpkg` command line? And did you use `name-of-your-python-3.6-package`literally or did you use the real name of the package?

Comment: No as i said nothing is installing :( looks like formating system is the only option left, I went to the ubuntu official site here "https://pkgs.org/download/usb-creator-gtk"  to install this package "usb-creator-gtk" but doesn't work either, and no not literally i tried every command to remove/update/install python but nothing is installing and removing from the system.

Comment: This command "sudo dpkg --configure -a" returning this `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)` and alot of other details... and at the last it says `dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64
 usb-creator-common
 anydesk
 teamviewer
 gnome-menus
`

Comment: @Vipertecpro, I am sorry to read that those commands do not work. Maybe you can try also `sudo apt install -f`. If you can wait, maybe we can get advanced help from @oldfred. Otherwise, the alternative is to backup what needs to be backed up and reinstall.

Comment: It's okay I already took a backup of my system, I can wait really if any problem can be solved by programmatically, I will be most happy to understand and learn what's the core of it.

Comment: @Vipertecpro, It is also a good idea to check the drive's hardware and the file system when booted from a live drive according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983#972983) before you reinstall.

Comment: @Vipertecpro Note, pkgs.org is **not** "the ubuntu official site",

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3.5 python2.7 python2.7-dev  
sudo reboot
```

After the computer reboots open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt purge python3.6  
sudo apt update   
sudo apt upgrade
```

If `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt upgrade` result in an error message, please post the error message in a comment, especially if you are asked to run an additional command.

In order to reinstall usb-creator-gtk. you must add a new line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing with the following command:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line to the sources.list file:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Please check the sources.list file carefully before you save it to make sure that there are not two duplicate `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse` lines. There must be only one unique line, not two duplicate lines, and that unique line must not be commented out by being started with a `#` character.

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the sources.list file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Run the following commands to update the list of available software and reinstall usb-creator-gtk:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

I can't see your sources.list file from here, so maybe it already had a `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse` line in it in which case the above commands would do nothing. So reinstall usb-creator-gtk manually instead. Download usb-creator-gtk_0.3.2ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb from the [official Ubuntu website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/usb-creator-gtk/download). Open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains the usb-creator-gtk_0.3.2ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb file that you downloaded. Install usb-creator-gtk with the following command:

```
sudo apt install ./usb-creator-gtk_0.3.2ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade` return `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package usb-creator-gtk needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: @Vipertecpro Please run the commands that I added to my answer to reinstall usb-creator-gtk.