# Kubuntu 20.04 smart data

Tags: kubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

In Kubuntu 20.04 i have the **KDE partition manager** application where *SMART status* is unknown.
What application do i need for **SMART data** in Kubuntu 20.04 ?

[image]

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors/972983#972983) may help you get the S.M.A.R.T. information.

Answer (score 0):

The application DISKS from GNOME utility for dealing with storage devices.