# Problems with startup after power failure

Tags: boot

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04, and it used to work pretty smoothly till now. However, since an abnormal shutdown due to power outage the system takes a LOT of time to start. The booting process is normal till the boot screen but after that it gets stuck at a blank screen and takes around 10-15 seconds to load the desktop. Any idea what's up?

Comment: I suggest that you check/repair the file system(s) of Ubuntu. Boot from another drive, for example an Ubuntu live USB drive, and run the checking program. See [this link (scroll down ...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors/972983#972983). This may or may not be enough to make things work well again, but it is a good start.

Comment: You can also check your logs for clues to see what's up.